# Cannot understand a solution to evaluating $C_{2}^{2000}+C_{5}^{2000}+C_{8}^{2000}+\cdots+C_{2000}^{2000}$

Tags: combinatorics

There is a problem in the book *101 Problems in Algebra* which is:

> Evaluate this $$C_{2}^{2000}+C_{5}^{2000}+C_{8}^{2000}+\cdots+C_{2000}^{2000}$$

I cannot understand the solution (shown below) to this problem. How can the statement is equal to the next line in the green marked box? Can anyone make me understand?

[image]

Comment: Mark Bennet's and Yiorgos S. Smyrlis's answers will show you why the equation is true.